# Is it valid to use the full dataset to determine important variables and a partial datasets for training a classification algorithm?

Tags: classification, sampling, assumptions

***Given a dataset with n variables and a binary outcome:***

Are there assumption violations/risks to drawing conclusions if the entire dataset is used to determine which variables are valid *if* the second part of the analysis will rely on generating a classification algorithm using test and training datasets?

In essence, can I determine odds ratios with the entire dataset and then go and develop a classification algorithm by sampling to create with test and training sets?

**Or** should I be using the training set to determine the odds ratios of a given variable?

*Any feedback is appreciated, I'm hoping not to collect another [tumbleweed badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed)*.